# Animation Not Working For Skills Bar In HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-deployment

I am trying to include a skills bar in my webpage but I am not for some reason, getting the animation effect. I tried copying the code for the skills bar into another platform to run and that works fine, but when I copy and paste my code into my project, the animation doesn't work.

MY HTML/CSS

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  place-items: center;
  background: transparent;
}

::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: black;
}

.skill-bars {
  padding: 25px 30px;
  width: 615px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.skill-bars .bar {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.skill-bars .bar:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.skill-bars .bar .info {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.skill-bars .bar .info span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.skill-bars .bar .progress-line {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

.bar .progress-line span {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: black;
  animation: animate 1s 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}

.bar .progress-line.html span {
  width: 90%;
}

.bar .progress-line.css span {
  width: 60%;
}

.bar .progress-line.jquery span {
  width: 85%;
}

.bar .progress-line.python span {
  width: 50%;
}

.bar .progress-line.mysql span {
  width: 75%;
}

.progress-line span::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.progress-line span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText2 {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.progress-line.html span::after {
  content: "90%";
}

.progress-line.css span::after {
  content: "60%";
}

.progress-line.jquery span::after {
  content: "85%";
}

.progress-line.python span::after {
  content: "50%";
}

.progress-line.mysql span::after {
  content: "75%";
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>What I am Working On</h2>
    </div>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/skills.css">
    <div class="skill-bars">
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="info">
          <span>HTML</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-line html">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="info">
          <span>CSS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-line css">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="info">
          <span>jQuery</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-line jquery">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="info">
          <span>Python</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-line python">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="info">
          <span>MySQL</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-line mysql">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


</section>
```

This is the exact code I have in my project, and as you can see it works fine here and the animation is also working, but I have the exact same code in my project but over there it doesn't work at all. Why?

(please go on there and take a look at what's wrong because I cant seem to figure it out for an hour now.) The CSS of the skills bar is saved onto `assets/css/skills.css`
The HTML of the skills bar is located right after "Featured blogs of the day"**

This where I initially got the whole code for skills bar from: https://www.codingnepalweb.com/2020/09/animated-skills-bar-ui-design-using.html

Comment: Your project is private behind repl.it website, it can not be seen without registration. Also it works in snippet posted here so look for conflicts in CSS if you c/p that bar code from somewhere else...

Comment: I shared the link to my project, you should be able to access it

Comment: I am not able. Like i said. You are trying to do web dev, how about you open private window and try yourself before commenting that it "should" work. Basic debugging 101.

Comment: Well someone else is on my project right now, I dont know why u cant access. Also, I am not saying "it should work" I am just requiring some help/guidance because I tried what I could but cannot make the animation to work in my project. Thanks.

Comment: You might to register/sign-in if u havent used repl.it before

Comment: And I am just saying people can not help with your request as link to project is not working. And you can not really ask people to register anywhere. Pretty sure that goes against some policy around here, or it should.

Comment: Idk how else to link my whole project on here, cuz it is a lot

Comment: @ikiK is quite right. SO is not a free help plattform where you request help for your project and ppl will do the work for you. What you asking, is that someone looks through your entire code and fixes your issues. Even if someone would actually do this, then your request has no community interest as it wont help anyone elese in the futre. Also SO is not a plattform for hiring someone to help with your project.

Comment: Voting to close: The question is missing debugging details to reproduce the issue and to actually fix it. Also has no community interest as the code in question is private and require registration at that site.